# remove successive duplicates in array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I'm working on a function which removes the duplicates in an array.
The catch on this function is if the consecutive duplicates are less than 5 it will remain and 5 above will become a single number.

My problem is cant figure out the logic.

hope you can help me.

thanks.

**Sample code**

```
function removeDuplicates($array){
        $result = array();
        $lastVal = null;
        $temp_array = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            # code...
            if($value != $firstVal){

                $result[] = $value;   

            }else{

                $temp_array[] = $value;

            }

            $lastVal = $value;

        }

        return $result;

    }
```

**sample**

```
$array = array(1,2,4,1,1,1,1,0,8,7,2,0,0,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,2,4,1,5);
```

**expected result**

```
[1,2,4,1,1,1,1,0,8,7,2,0,0,8,2,4,1,5]
```

Comment: What is `$firstVal` in your code ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here:**

```
    <?php

    $array = array(1,2,4,1,1,1,1,0,8,7,2,0,0,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,2,4,1,5);
    $test = removeDuplicates($array);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($test);


function removeDuplicates($array){
    $result = [];
    $count = 1;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= count($array)-1; $i++) {
        if ($array[$i] == $array[$i - 1]) {
            $count++;
        } else {
            if ($count >= 5) {
                array_splice($array, $i-$count, $count-1);
            }
            $count = 1;
        }
    }

    return $array;

}
```

**Output:**

```
array(18) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(4)
  [3]=>
  int(1)
  [4]=>
  int(1)
  [5]=>
  int(1)
  [6]=>
  int(1)
  [7]=>
  int(0)
  [8]=>
  int(8)
  [9]=>
  int(7)
  [10]=>
  int(2)
  [11]=>
  int(0)
  [12]=>
  int(0)
  [13]=>
  int(8)
  [14]=>
  int(2)
  [15]=>
  int(4)
  [16]=>
  int(1)
  [17]=>
  int(5)
}
```

Comment: This will work for `less than 5 it will remain and 5 above`, you can send second variable for this to make it dynamically

Comment: Can you test some of these: `[1,2,4,1,1,1,1,1,0,8,7,2,0,0,8,2,4,1,5]`, `[1,2,4,1,1,1,1,1,0,8,7,2,0,0,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,2,4,1,5]`, `[1,2,4,1,1,1,1,0,8,7,2,0,0,8,8,8,2,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,5]`...?

Comment: I didn't downvote just for reseting `$count` mistake. You also made a logic mistake in line `array_splice($array, $i-$count, $count-1);`. Looks fine now, so vote is back

Comment: It matched expected output by pure accident! :D When your counter wasn't resetting, it counted to 4 in `[1,1,1,1]`, then to 5 in `[0,0]`, and then **forward** from current `$i` position it was removing those eights :D :D :D. This was your code `array_splice($array, $i, $count+1);`

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

function removeDuplicates($array){
    $freq = 5;

    $result = [];
    $size = count($array);

    $counts = [];
    for($i=0;$i<$size;++$i) $counts[] = 0;

    $counts[$size-1] = 1;

    for($i=$size-2;$i>=0;--$i){
        $counts[$i] = 1;
        if($array[$i] === $array[$i+1]) $counts[$i] = $counts[$i+1] + 1;            
    }

    for($i=0;$i<$size;++$i){
        $result[] = $array[$i];
        if($counts[$i] >= $freq){
            $i += $counts[$i] - 1; 
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$array = array(1,2,4,1,1,1,1,0,8,7,2,0,0,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,2,4,1,5);

print_r(removeDuplicates($array));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/mvjOq

- Above is an O(n) algorithm(with O(n) extra space) where we first pre-compute how much count does the current number have consecutively.
- Now, when we iterate again, we check if current array's number has a `count value >= frequency`. Here, frequency is `5`.
- If the count is less than frequency, iterate usually. Otherwise we jump directly to the next worthy number to process with the help of frequency stored in `$count[$i]` for that particular number. This would work even when your frequency to be opted for is 1000 or more.

Comment: Looks like the only working solution to me. I don't know should I downvote more everything else, but I upvoted this one

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for my case. But if the keys are associative, it will lose the original keys. A solution for numeric keys is to use `$result[$i]`. If the keys are alphanumeric, then my suggestion won't work.

Answer (score 0):

as an option

```
removeDuplicates(array(1,2,4,1,1,1,1,0,8,7,2,0,0,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,2,4,1,5));

function removeDuplicates($arr){
    $count_duplicates = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $key => $item){
        if($item == $arr[$key+1]){
            $count_duplicates++;
        }else{
            if($count_duplicates >= 5){
                for($i = 0; $i < $count_duplicates; $i++){
                    unset($arr[$key-$i]);
                }
            }
            $count_duplicates = 0;
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, there's undefined offset on this line `if($item == $arr[$key+1]){`

Comment: `$arr[$key+1]` - is the next element of array, in this moment `if($item == $arr[$key+1])` , we check the similarity of the current and next elements

Answer (score -2):

It should something like this

$array = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "4", "2", "1");

$result = array_unique($array);

Comment: Did you check your code? It's not what OP wants.(didn't downvote)

Comment: The output doesn't match what OP wants. He doesn't want just unique elements.

Comment: Please read question carefully. From question **The catch on this function is if the consecutive duplicates are less than 5 it will remain and 5 above will become a single number.**